# How to create a new database in mongodb using pyspark?

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark

I am working on a project which is tenant based project means for every client creating a new database. For now, to create a new database I am using mongo compass and manually creating database on clicking new or plus sign.

But I want to create a new database in mongodb using the pyspark. I have a mongo connection string. Please suggest me to how to create?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `pyspark` but typical mongo workflow to create db is to run any write [operation](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/create-database). If you want to create a db before any using of it, you can run a simple insert operation or, for example, create a [collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) inside this db